# Images not showing on mobile device but showing on desktop, using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, css, phonegap

I am doing a project for college but having trouble with images displaying on the mobile device.
[Desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJWDO.jpg)

So the image in the background displays on the desktop as shown above. and below is the mobile application with no background loading.

[mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNN3A.png)

This is my code. My image location is correct seeing as the desktop loads it and i got the style code from another stack overflow answer but it hasn't helped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<style>
#bg {
background: url(images/logo.jpg) repeat scroll 50% 0px / cover transparent;
background-image: url(images/logo.jpg);
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}
</style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, 
user-scalable=yes, width=device-width">

    <title>ITCOA</title>

</head>
<div id="bg">
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:80px"> Welcome to IT Carlow Orientation App </h1>
        <div id="navcontainer" style="margin-left:150px;margin-top:100px;">
            <button type="button" id="findPathButton"onclick="parent.location='findPlace.html'">Find a place!</button><br><br>
            <button type="button" id="showMapsButton" onclick="parent.location='showMaps.html'">Show Maps!</button>
        </div>

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help.

Updated code

```
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>ITCOA</title>
<script src="cordova.js" defer></script>
<style>
  #bg {
    background: url('images/logo.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
  }

  button {
    margin: 15px 0 15px 0;
    display: block;
  }

</style>
 </head>

  <body>
    <div id="bg">
      <h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:80px"> Welcome to IT Carlow 
Orientation App </h1>
  <div id="navcontainer" style="margin-left:150px;margin-top:100px;">
    <button type="button" id="findPathButton" 
onclick="parent.location='findPlace.html'">Find a place!</button>
    <button type="button" id="showMapsButton" 
onclick="parent.location='showMaps.html'">Show Maps!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `<style>` tag should be in your `<head>`. `<div id="bg">` is above html body element. Why `#bg` id has 2 background statements? `background: url(images/logo.jpg) repeat scroll 50% 0px / cover transparent;` and 
`background-image: url(images/logo.jpg);` ? Please at least read [W3s](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp). Other thing is that your code is overall terrible. I advice to stop using inline styling elements and also stop using inline javaScript. You can add `<script src="cordova.js" defer></script>` to your `<head>` with `defer` flag. Consider adding css file to your project and add all of your styles there. Also since you already have js file you can put your click behavior there by `addEventListener()` Method.

**Update:**
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NightKn8/8ucq0emm/)

**Update2:**
[image: kitty]

Comment: ok thanks for the comment, but does terrible code have an effect on my problem? or have you explained anything here to help my problem? also i only have my style here because im trying to get it working, it isnt how it will actually look

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you this works. Can you upload your new code or create jsfiddle?. What mobile phone are you using?

Comment: we thought it might be that the android version on our phones was too new but we tried an older android phone and still no image!

Comment: At first I would go and try replace `background:...` line to `background: red;` and see if the background is red in both mobile and desktop. If background is red then check if you can load image from some external source like I did. If you make it visible on both mobile and desktop then consider experimenting with your original image path `images/logo.jpg`.

Comment: we fixed it, the problem was that a jpeg file couldn't be used would you believe! Instead we have to use png files. No clue as to why, thanks for the help all the same!